# Databinding @Bindable with indirect Getters

Tags: android, data-binding

In my model class I have a start date which has a bindable getter and a setter that notifies about changes. But I also have a getter that returns the date as a formatted string. The date updates in the View when it changes, the formatted String does not. How would I accomplish this?

Heres the code:

```
var start: DateTime
    @Bindable get() = _start
    set(value) {
        _start = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.start)
    }

val formattedStartDate: String
    @Bindable get() = _start.toString(dateFormatter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.formattedStartDate)` in the `start` setter as well